# How to uniformly sample from singular matrices

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I would like to uniformly sample from all singular n by n Bernoulli matrices (that is each entry is 1 or 0 with probability 1/2). I could of course just sample from all n by n Bernoulli matrices and reject those that are non-singular but for any moderate n that is extremely inefficient.

As an example, of the 10000 random 100 by 100 matrices I tested, none were singular.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Here is some test python code to show the problem.

```
import numpy as np
iters = 10000
n = 100
count = 0
for i in xrange(iters):
    A = np.random.randint(2, size = (n,n))
    if (np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) < n):
        count += 1
print count
```

Posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155185/how-to-sample-uniformly-from-singular-matrices on Jan 20.

---

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155185/how-to-sample-uniformly-from-singular-matrices  now has a suggested algorithm to solve this problem. The remaining challenge is to work out how to implement it.

Comment: One idea you can try is to generate the first n-1 rows, and then generate the last row as a linear combination of the previous n-1. This will guarantee a singular matrix, but I'm not sure how you'd go about the uniformness.

Comment: Yes I have just realized. Anyway, maybe a useful reference for future generations http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0753.pdf :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, on the spectrum of questions ranging from programming through computer science to research level mathematics, this question is on the math end of the spectrum.

Comment: @mbeckish I disagree. There is a large overlap between mathematics/computer science and programming. In my case I have some very slow code that I would like to make faster :) It just happens the question fits all three categories.  I feel your real reason for saying it is off-topic is that it might be very hard. Don't underestimate programmers!

Comment: @marshall - Maybe I misunderstood your question.  Are you looking for a faster implementation of your "test N random matrices" algorithm, or are you looking for a mathematical theorem you can exploit to reduce the search space and make it easier to find the singular matrices?

Comment: @mbeckish I want it to run faster. To do this I need a better algorithm as simple optimisations won't work.  I believe speed improvements that  require a better algorithm are on topic.

Comment: @mbeckish: He's got a practical, answerable question that's manifestly about programming.  It just happens to be really hard.  Questions are apparently supposed to be judged on their question content, not on what form the answers are likely to have.

Comment: @marshall - If I were to submit a brute-force algorithm for solving 3SAT problems, and then ask the community for a polynomial time solution, that would be a theoretical research question not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @mbeckish: "Polynomial time" doesn't mean practical, so it isn't clear that that's on-topic here.

Comment: @tmyklebu - Are you saying the OP would find an exponential time solution acceptable?

Comment: @mbeckish: Go ahead and ask him.

Comment: @tmyklebu - No thanks, but you are free to. :)

Comment: @mbeckish I think you are talking about well known open problems. Those could well be off topic here. I am not sure that is what I asked though.  You could also be worried about problems where, unknown to the OP, it turns out that a significant improvement in theory is needed to gain better performance. In those cases I would agree that once that is discovered migrating to cstheory might be a good idea. That isn't the case here though either.

Comment: @marhsall - You are right - this may not be an open problem.  And if someone comes by with a known solution, that's great.  I put in one vote that this seems like an open problem, but if 4 other people don't feel the same way, your question will remain open.  Please don't take offense at close votes - it's just a tool to help lower the signal to noise ratio on the site.  It in no way refelects negatively upon you personally.

Comment: @mbeckish: Frivolous close votes are a real nuisance here.  And, as in this discussion, they can increase the SNR.

Comment: @tmyklebu - There's no reason for close votes to be a problem. First of all, it takes 5 like-minded people to vote to close.  In this case, there was nobody else, so a single close vote causes no harm. Second, questions can be voted to be reopened.  Not sure why there is so much attention being given to one person's opinion on whether this question is appropriate for this site.

Comment: @mbeckish: There's plenty of reason.  If a question gets frivolously closed, you can't answer it until it's reopened.  Getting a question reopened takes effort and time.  It may not be worthwhile to expend that effort and time and monitor the question until it's reopened.  Also, your argument that *your* close vote has done no harm is specious; individual contributors to collaborative efforts deserve credit, whether wanted or not, for their contributions, whether helpful or harmful.

Comment: @tmyklebu - That's the nature of a voting system.  For every vote to close, there will be people who disagree.  That doesn't mean we should attack the voter, or even view the vote as harmful.  It is the mechanism that is given to tally people's opinions on whether the questions should remain open or not - nothing more.

Comment: @RobertDodier - How is that any different than your effort to drive away a vote that you disagree with?  People have differing opinions, and every opinion is heard.  Why the uproar?

Comment: @mbeckish You seem to have forgotten that voting to close a question is a power that you have that is quite a bit stronger than just commenting, as most people can. "Every opinion is heard" -- not after a question is closed. "Why the uproar?" -- because SO culture leans towards hand-wringing and hectoring, when that's not any necessary consequence of being a Q&A web site. Every unnecessarily closed question is a wasted opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

The comments drifted away a bit, so I'm posting this as an answer:

There is a paper here: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2729950_Efficient_Generation_of_Random_Nonsingular_Matrices/file/e0b4951d5a6fcc7e67.pdf that describes how to generate non-singular, and, as an extension, singular matrices over finite fields. Since in programming real numbers are, to some extent, finite, so I think it should be applicable here.

Comment: A dependence over GF(2) won't necessarily be a dependence over Q.  (Neat paper, though.)

Comment: +1.  I think if the OP had suggested an algorithm from a particular paper and asked for help with the implementation, that would be a great question.  Asking the community to scour the internet for papers, not so much.

Comment: I haven't read and understood the paper, but I saw pseudocode for generating singular matrices on page 7. Is it unclear in the paper?

Comment: @IvanVergiliev Oops. I scanned too quickly. So the only problem is that it solves the wrong problem :) (Over GF(2) not over the reals.) Thanks for the paper reference though!

Comment: @mbeckish Again you are too negative.  I didn't ask anyone to scour the internet. I asked for help which is the whole point of stackoverflow!  If your concern is that I didn't find an easily findable solution online then please say so.

Comment: I think since you don't need (and can't really have) infinite precision, you can model this with a finite field. E.g. define a field consisting of each number of the type p/q, where -1000 <= p, q <= 1000. Then apply the algorithm from the paper over this field. Then, translate numbers smaller than 0 to 0 in the output matrix, and numbers greater then 0 to 1 in the output matrix.

Comment: @IvanVergiliev: That's not a field, though.

Comment: @tmyklebu Hm, addition and multiplication can go outside of the field, right? Algebra classes were a while ago. Still, what prevents one from doing the same thing with any of the fields from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field , and then doing some mapping from this field to [0, 1] ?

Comment: @IvanVergiliev: The mapping is what's going to ruin everything.

Comment: Note that the question wants matrices were the entries are either 0 or 1, not real numbers in [0, 1]. (Though I'm not sure going via finite fields would work in that case either.)

Comment: A solution has been posted on mathoverflow now in case you were interested.